# How do i configure my contact form to receive messages

Tags: javascript, php, html, smtp, imap

I am trying to configure my contact from to my remote server. The technical guys from my hosting have issued me this settings for my mail setting:

(POP3/IMAP) & outgoing mail (SMTP) server name is:  mail.yourdomain.com
ports are: POP3 -> 110, IMAP -> 143 and SMTP -> 25 or 2525

Unfortunately, i do not know where to insert that into my php contact file.

these are the contact files:

contact.html

```
<form role="form" action="contact.php" method="post">
                                                <div class="text-fields">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bbname" id="bbname" placeholder="name:">
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="bbemail" id="bbemail" placeholder="email:">
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bbphone" id="bbphone" placeholder="phone:">
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="submit-area">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="message:" name="bbmessage" id="bbmessage"></textarea>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="bbsubmit">Send it</button>
                                                </div>
          </form>
```

contact.php

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['bbname'];
$field_email = $_POST['bbemail'];
$field_phone = $_POST['bbphone'];
$field_message = $_POST['bbmessage'];

$mail_to = 'me@mydomain.com';
$subject = 'Message from '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone: '.$field_phone."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. I will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'contact.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to me@mail.com');
        window.location = 'contact.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you rather use ready Mailer class for that - http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ is the best choice. I use it for many years and you can configure SMTP connection very easy